# Why language change required app to restart in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multilingual

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem in language conversion

For English I am using code like this

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

            //to set the selected language at runtime (dynamically)
            NSLog(@"Language set=Malay");
            [NSBundle setLanguage:@"en"];
            MenuScreen *menu=[[MenuScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuScreen" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:menu animated:YES];
```

For Thai Language I used code like this

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"th-TH", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

            //to set the selected language at runtime (dynamically)
            NSLog(@"Language set=Malay");
            [NSBundle setLanguage:@"th-TH"];
            MenuScreen *menu=[[MenuScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuScreen" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:menu animated:YES];
```

But every time it required to restart app. Is there is any solution for this or any thing I am doing wrong.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you explain the app flow ? and who you want to switch the language.

Comment: if you have put this code into the app-delegate it will run only once – when you restart your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muju I created sample project and I worked getting solution for your question.I got the solution perfectly.

In my below sample I want to change "**Welcome to Thailand**" to "ยินดีต้อนรับสู่ประเทศไทย".I use localization concept for this.

Before going to steps, I want you to see my storyboard designing

[image]

Please follow the below steps.

**STEP 1:Click Project->info->Localization->Click +**

**Now it shows the drop down list of Language.From that we should select Thai**

[image]

**STEP 2:Once we choose or select the Language from drop down list,it shows the below window and we need to click Finish button**

[image]

Now it looks like below

[image]

**STEP 3:Create the String File for the localization and set the name.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

above I set String file name as `LocalizationThai`

**STEP 4:Click the LocalizationThai.strings also click the File Inspector.Click the Localization inside the File Inspector.Now it shows the below pop up box.**

[image]

**STEP 5:Click Localize.Once you Localize,it shows below like this**

[image]

**STEP 6:Click 3 Checkboxes**

[image]

Now in bundle we have 3 files under LocalizationThai.strings

[image]

**STEP 7:Write your required changing text in string files.**

***i.In LocalizationThai.strings(Thai) file I write below text***

[image]

***ii.In LocalizationThai.strings(English) file I write below text***

[image]

***iii.In LocalizationThai.strings(Base) file I write below text***

[image]

**STEP 8:Create the Header File for the multiple Languages.**

[image]

**STEP 9 : set the Header name(I set header name as LocalizationHeader) and define Languages in the Header file like below**

[image]

LocalizationHeader.h

```
#ifndef LocalizationHeader_h
#define LocalizationHeader_h


#define ENGLISH 0
#define THAI 1


#endif /* LocalizationHeader_h */
```

**STEP 10:Implement the below coding part**

Localization.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LocalizationHeader.h"
@interface Localization : NSObject
+(Localization *)sharedInstance;
+(NSString*) strSelectLanguage:(int)curLang;
+(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key;
@end
```

Localization.m

```
#import "Localization.h"
int currentLanguage,selectedrow;
@implementation Localization

+(Localization *)sharedInstance
{
    static Localization *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Localization alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}


+(NSString*) strSelectLanguage:(int)curLang{
    if(curLang==THAI){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"th", nil]forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }
    else{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil]forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    currentLanguage=curLang;
    NSString *strLangSelect = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
    return strLangSelect;
}

+(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{
    NSString *path;
    NSString *strSelectedLanguage = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
    //When we check with iPhone,iPad device it shows "en-US".So we need to change it to "en"
    if([strSelectedLanguage hasPrefix:@"en-"])
        strSelectedLanguage = [strSelectedLanguage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"en-US" withString:@"en"];
    if([strSelectedLanguage isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"en"]]){
        currentLanguage=ENGLISH;
        selectedrow=ENGLISH;
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
    }
    else{
        currentLanguage=THAI;
        selectedrow=THAI;
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"th" ofType:@"lproj"];
    }
    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:@"LocalizationThai"];
    return str;
}
@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Localization.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    Localization *localization;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblWelcome;
- (IBAction)actionChangeLanToThai:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)actionChangeLangToEng:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize lblWelcome;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    localization = [Localization sharedInstance];
    lblWelcome.text = [Localization languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Welcome to Thailand"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)actionChangeLanToThai:(id)sender {
    [Localization strSelectLanguage:THAI];
    lblWelcome.text = [Localization languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Welcome to Thailand"];

}

- (IBAction)actionChangeLangToEng:(id)sender {
    [Localization strSelectLanguage:ENGLISH];
    lblWelcome.text = [Localization languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Welcome to Thailand"];
}
@end
```

When I run the app first

[image]

Then When I change the Language from English to Thai

[image]

Again when I change it to English

[image]

You have to follow the same steps for XIB

**Below is for XIB**

I create the ViewController with XIB.ViewController name is RootViewController
[image]

Now see the designing part
[image]

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic) RootViewController *viewController;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;     
  }
```

RootViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "Localization.h"
 @interface RootViewController : UIViewController{
    Localization *localization;
 }
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblWelcomeThaiLang;
 - (IBAction)actionChangeLangToThai:(id)sender;
 - (IBAction)actionChangeLangToEng:(id)sender;
 @end
```

RootViewController.m

```
 #import "RootViewController.h"
 @interface RootViewController ()
 @end
 @implementation RootViewController
 @synthesize lblWelcomeThaiLang;
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
 }
 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
 - (IBAction)actionChangeLangToThai:(id)sender {
    [Localization strSelectLanguage:THAI];
    lblWelcomeThaiLang.text = [Localization languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Welcome to Thailand"];
 }
 - (IBAction)actionChangeLangToEng:(id)sender {
    [Localization strSelectLanguage:ENGLISH];
    lblWelcomeThaiLang.text = [Localization languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Welcome to Thailand"];
 }
 @end
```

Now see the result

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using xib is that a problem.

Comment: do you have this code in Swift language.. I need it.. could you please update your code in swift

Answer (score 0):

Hi in ios we have bundle for to store the localization files..
When we switch the language using
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"th-TH", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

it just change the locale of current application not the bundle of localization.

To change the language inApp you need to change the language bundle for that.
To change language inApp you need to use

BundleLocalization

https://github.com/cmaftuleac/BundleLocalization

[BundleLocalization sharedInstance].language = @"de";
NSLog(@"Application language: %@", [BundleLocalization sharedInstance].language);